# Query performance become slower after upgrade to MySQL 8.0.20

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7, functions, mysql-8.0

I have found bug/issue after update the MySQL Server from 5.7 to 8.0.20.

When I run a query with the user-define function in 5.7(same session), the duration for each query is constant and stable.

But while I run the same query in the 8.0.20(same session), the duration for each query is kept increasing.

I have tried running the query without the user-define function in 8.0.20, the duration for each query is back to normal. In the second test with the user-define function but without the query in the function, the result is also normal.

So I suspect the query in the user-define function is the root cause to this bug/issue.

But I cannot think of why this is only happening in 8.0.20, but its work great in 5.7.

Below are the sample result, table structure and the user-define function. Please let me know If there is any additional information is needed.

Result in 5.7:    https://pastebin.com/Wexs69UP

Result in 8.0.20: https://pastebin.com/kBq6DLGy

Table A

```
CREATE TABLE `item_2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receive_dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Table B

```
CREATE TABLE `holiday` (
  `holiday` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

user-define Function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` FUNCTION `min_diff`(start_datetime datetime, end_datetime datetime) RETURNS int
BEGIN

/*declare*/
DECLARE min_diff int;
DECLARE off_day int;
DECLARE temp_start_datetime datetime;
DECLARE temp_end_datetime datetime;
DECLARE temp_start_date date;
DECLARE temp_end_date date;
DECLARE holiday boolean;

SET temp_start_date = date_format(start_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d');
SET temp_end_date = date_format(end_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d');
SET temp_start_datetime = start_datetime;
SET temp_end_datetime = end_datetime;
SET off_day = 0;

/*If Star date greater than End Date*/
if temp_start_datetime > end_datetime
then return 0;
end if;

/*Skip 1st day*/
set temp_start_date = temp_start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

/*loop from start days to end day*/
while temp_start_date < temp_end_date do

/*exclude holiday*/
SET holiday = (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `holiday_list` WHERE `date`=temp_start_date));

/*if weekend or holiday */
/*  5-saturday
    6-sunday*/
if (weekday(temp_start_date)=5 OR weekday(temp_start_date)=6) OR holiday
then set off_day = off_day+1;
end if;

/*plus one days*/
set temp_start_date = temp_start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

END WHILE;

SET min_diff = (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, temp_start_datetime, temp_end_datetime));
SET min_diff = min_diff - (off_day*24*60);

/*return days diff*/
RETURN min_diff;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the bad grammar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469293/database-performance-drop-after-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0-20?noredirect=1#comment111610311_62469293 previous post in StackOverFlow

Comment: You have a "Stored Function" or "Stored Routine".  A "User Defined Function" ("UDF") is something different.